# How to calculate yield spread?

Tags: spread, yield

I came across this multiple choice question on yield spread and I can't understand why the reasoning for the selected answer is correct.Can you confirm or clarify ?

(
emphasis in the text is mine)
[image]

> The bond's market price of 103.73 can be computed by discounting its
>   cash flows continuously at 4.0% per annum, which is represented by the
>   flat yellow line. Specifically:
>
> $3.00e^{-.04*0.5} + 3.00e^{-.04*1.0} + 3.00e^{-.04*1.5} +
> > 103.00e^{-.04*2}
> > = 103.73$.
>
> The bond's same market price of $104.73 can also be derived by
>   discounting the same cash flows according to the continuous discount
>   rates given by the the steep blue line. The lower steep line, which
>   shows a rate of 0.40% at six months, is actually two nearby curves: a
>   swap rate curve and nearby spot rate curve.
>
> Both start at 0.40% but, as the spot rate curve is slightly steeper,
>   by year 2.0, the **spot rate is 1.61%** while the swap rate is 1.60%.
>   For this purpose, we assume both the spot and are risk-free curves;
>   e.g., US Treasury.
>
> Each of the following is true about this bond EXCEPT which is
>   **false**?
>
> a) The bond's yield-to-maturity is 4.0%
>
> b) The yield spread, represented by the solid red vertical arrow, is
>   the difference between 4.0% (yellow line) and 0.40% (spot rate at six
>   months)
>
> c) If the price of the bond decreased due solely to perceived credit
>   risk of bond (without any change in market risk), the upper curves
>   (yellow and blue) would shift up
>
> d) The z-spread, represented by the dashed red vertical arrow, is the
>   difference between the (upper steep) blue line and the (lower steep)
>   spot rate; e.g., 2.42% = 4.03% - 1.61%

The given answer is:

> **B.** The yield spread is the "single-point" difference between the yield to maturity (YTM) and the corresponding riskless spot rate; in
>   this case, yield spread ~= 4.0% -
>   1.61% ~= 2.39%. As the endpoints at year 2.0 are near to each other, this yield is only slightly less than the z-spread of 2.42%, due
>   primarily to the fact that the upper blue line endpoint must
>   necessarily be slightly greater than the 4.0% YTM. If the
>   corresponding riskless swap rate is necessarily interpolated, then
>   this yield spread is an i-spread

Isn't yield spread the difference in yield to maturity between the corporate bond and the risk free bond? In this question, 1.61 is the 2 year spot and not a yield to maturity. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you add the source of the question for reference's sake?

Comment: The question comes from an FRM exam prep website Bionicturtle.com